# How to use IEqualityComparer<T>.Equals() in ToLookUp<T>() Extension

Tags: c#, vb.net, .net-4.0, hashcode, equality

I stumbled upon [an article](http://devlicio.us/blogs/billy_mccafferty/archive/2009/05/22/why-doesn-t-iequalitycomparer-use-equals-in-linq-s-intersect-including-a-stroll-down-the-lane-of-gethashcode-and-the-birthday-paradox.aspx) regarding the [Birthday Paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_paradox) and it's implications when overriding the `GetHashCode` method, I find myself in a bind.

In tests, we found that in calls to the [`ToLookup()` Extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549346.aspx), only `GetHashcode` is used, despite providing the implementation for Equals.

I think I understand *why* this happens, the internal working of `ToLookup`, `HashSet`, `Dictionary`, etc, use the HashCodes to store and/or index their elements?

Is there a way to somehow provide the functionality so that the equality comparison is actual performed using the equals method?  Or should I not be concerned with the collisions?  I haven't done the maths myself, but according to the first article I linked, you would only need 77,163 elements in a list before reaching a 50% chance of collision.

If I understand this correctly, an `Equals()` override that compares property by property such as

```
Return (a.Property1 == b.Property1 && a.Property2 == b.Property2 && ...)
```

should have a zero chance of collision?  So how can I get my `ToLookup()` to equality compare this way?

---

In case you need an example of what I mean:

*C#*

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DoStuff();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public class AnEntity
    {
        public int KeyProperty1 { get; set; }
        public int KeyProperty2 { get; set; }
        public int KeyProperty3 { get; set; }
        public string OtherProperty1 { get; set; }
        public List<string> OtherProperty2 { get; set; }
    }

    public class KeyEntity
    {
        public int KeyProperty1 { get; set; }
        public int KeyProperty2 { get; set; }
        public int KeyProperty3 { get; set; }
    }

    public static void DoStuff()
    {
        var a = new AnEntity {KeyProperty1 = 1, KeyProperty2 = 2, KeyProperty3 = 3, OtherProperty1 = "foo"};
        var b = new AnEntity {KeyProperty1 = 1, KeyProperty2 = 2, KeyProperty3 = 3, OtherProperty1 = "bar"};
        var c = new AnEntity {KeyProperty1 = 999, KeyProperty2 = 999, KeyProperty3 = 999, OtherProperty1 = "yada"};

        var entityList = new List<AnEntity> { a, b, c };

        var lookup = entityList.ToLookup(n => new KeyEntity {KeyProperty1 = n.KeyProperty1, KeyProperty2 = n.KeyProperty2, KeyProperty3 = n.KeyProperty3});

        // I want these to all return true
        Debug.Assert(lookup.Count == 2);
        Debug.Assert(lookup[new KeyEntity {KeyProperty1 = 1, KeyProperty2 = 2, KeyProperty3 = 3}].First().OtherProperty1 == "foo");
        Debug.Assert(lookup[new KeyEntity {KeyProperty1 = 1, KeyProperty2 = 2, KeyProperty3 = 3}].Last().OtherProperty1 == "bar");
        Debug.Assert(lookup[new KeyEntity {KeyProperty1 = 999, KeyProperty2 = 999, KeyProperty3 = 999}].Single().OtherProperty1 == "yada");
    }

}
```

*VB*

```
Module Program

    Public Sub Main(args As String())
        DoStuff()
        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub

    Public Class AnEntity
        Public Property KeyProperty1 As Integer
        Public Property KeyProperty2 As Integer
        Public Property KeyProperty3 As Integer
        Public Property OtherProperty1 As String
        Public Property OtherProperty2 As List(Of String) 
    End Class

    Public Class KeyEntity
        Public Property KeyProperty1 As Integer
        Public Property KeyProperty2 As Integer
        Public Property KeyProperty3 As Integer
    End Class

    Public Sub DoStuff()
        Dim a = New AnEntity With {.KeyProperty1 = 1, .KeyProperty2 = 2, .KeyProperty3 = 3, .OtherProperty1 = "foo"}
        Dim b = New AnEntity With {.KeyProperty1 = 1, .KeyProperty2 = 2, .KeyProperty3 = 3, .OtherProperty1 = "bar"}
        Dim c = New AnEntity With {.KeyProperty1 = 999, .KeyProperty2 = 999, .KeyProperty3 = 999, .OtherProperty1 = "yada"}

        Dim entityList = New List(Of AnEntity) From {a, b, c}

        Dim lookup = entityList.ToLookup(Function(n) New KeyEntity With {.KeyProperty1 = n.KeyProperty1, .KeyProperty2 = n.KeyProperty2, .KeyProperty3 = n.KeyProperty3})

        ' I want these to all return true
        Debug.Assert(lookup.Count = 2)
        Debug.Assert(lookup(New KeyEntity With {.KeyProperty1 = 1, .KeyProperty2 = 2, .KeyProperty3 = 3}).First().OtherProperty1 = "foo")
        Debug.Assert(lookup(New KeyEntity With {.KeyProperty1 = 1, .KeyProperty2 = 2, .KeyProperty3 = 3}).Last().OtherProperty1 = "bar")
        Debug.Assert(lookup(New KeyEntity With {.KeyProperty1 = 999, .KeyProperty2 = 999, .KeyProperty3 = 999}).Single().OtherProperty1 = "yada")
    End Sub

End Module
```

---

I can get that to work with an override of `GetHashcode()`, no problems.  But I don't want to use `GetHashcode` because if I have, for example, 109,125 elements in my list, apparently I'm already at 75% chance of collision?  If it used aforementioned `Equals()` override, I think I'd be at 0%?

Comment: One way of doing this is in an implementation of IEqualityComparer, store the objects passed to `GetHashcode()` in a Dictionary. Perform the custom `Equals()` to confirm if objects passed are already held in the dictionary.  If not, increment a count, store the object indexed by the current count in the dictionary, and return the current count/index.  If the object did exist, return it's key from the dictionary.  That would be terrible expensive though; particularly if you consider you're only really concerned with collisions in particularly large lists? - is there a better way?

Comment: It seems I must have made a mistake in my original override of `GetHashcode` somewhere.  Having created a new implementation to match the code in this post, it did behave as expected and call `Equals()` when hashcodes matched...  I'll have a word with myself in the mirror and go work out what was wrong.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The article that you've linked to is completely misleading (and many of its comments highlight this).

`GetHashCode` is used where possible because it's fast; if there are hash collisions then `Equals` is used to disambiguate between the colliding items. So long as you [implement `Equals` and `GetHashCode` correctly](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode.aspx) -- whether in the types themselves or a custom `IEqualityComparer<T>` implementation -- then there won't be any problems.

The problem with your example code is that you're not overriding `Equals` and `GetHashCode` at all. This means that the the default implementations are used, and the default implementations use reference comparisons for reference types, not value comparisons.

This means that you're not getting hash collisions because the objects you're comparing against *are different to the original objects*, even though they have the same values. This, in turn, means that `Equals` just isn't required by your example code. Override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` correctly, or set up an `IEqualityComparer<T>` to do so, and everything will start working as you expect.

Comment: Hi @LukeH, I may have been misleading myself - sorry.  I mentioned the equals method I was using, but didn't add it to the code.  I'll do so now for clarity.  Then I'll go away and confirm that in fact ToLookup wasn't calling my Equals override (after reading your link to confirm I was doing it correctly).

Answer (score 1):

The birthday paradox does not apply in this situation. The birthday paradox relates to non-deterministic random sets, whereas hashcode computation is determinitic. the chances of 2 objects with different state sharing the same hashcode is much closer to 1 in a billion or so, certainly not as low as 77 thousand - therefore I dont think you have anything to worry about.

Comment: That makes sense... how do you work out the probability of collision on deterministic data? 77k was the point at which there was a 50% chance of collision, I wonder if the 1bill mark you mentioned drops in the same way?  Or is that the 50% point?

Comment: It all depends on the efficacy of your GetHashCode method. The standard implementation is pretty good, I just remember someone telling me that you have about a 1 in a billion chance of an incorrect match - which sounds about right. Sorry I cant be more specific on the maths used to calculate this :)